# Regex for removing special characters on a multilingual string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

The most common regex suggested for removing special characters seems to be this -

```
preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $string );
```

The problem is that it also removes non-English characters.

Is there a regex that removes special characters on all languages? Or the only solution is to explicitly match each **special character** and remove them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use instead:

```
preg_replace('/\P{Xan}+/u', '', $string );
```

`\p{Xan}` is all that is a number or a letter in any alphabet of the unicode table.
`\P{Xan}` is all that is not a number or a letter. It is a shortcut for `[^\p{Xan}]`

Comment: Thanks! I understand that `\P` is a character without Unicode property. Can you please explain `{Xan}`.

Comment: @A.Jesin: the uppercase P is only used to negate an unicode character class. For example `\p{Latin}` is a character class for all latin letters (like `[a-zA-Z]` but with accents), If you want to negate it to obtain all that is not a latin letter, you write `\P{Latin}`

Comment: @A.Jesin: You can find all unicode character classes in this document: http://pcre.org/pcre.txt

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
$string = preg_replace( '/[^\p{L}\p{N}]+/u', '', $string );
```